# In OpenTBS: How to use "new paragraph" carriage returns instead of "new line" in MS Word Templates

Tags: docx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have a PHP variable holding plain text that i need to insert into a MS Word Template using OpenTBS.

My Word placeholder is:

```
[onshow.introduction]
```

The problem is I use justification formatting, so I need actual "new paragraph" ie "carriage returns" (Enter) in Word. Instead all my newlines are translated into "new line" (shift-Enter), messing up my formatting.

I tried inserting 
, \r, \n, \n\r, \r\n, PHP_EOL - all of them just create newline characters instead of new paragraph characters in MS Word.

Is there any way to get "new paragraph" characters in Word from OpenTBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ms Word, a new paragraph is a complicated XML entity. Something like:

```
<w:p><w:r><w:t>My paragraph</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

and it can have extra attributes and extra sub-entities that can appear at several places.

So it would be very touchy and hazardous to replace your line-breaks with `</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>`.

The best and robust solution is to explode your text in several parts, and merge it on a block bounded an Ms Word paragraph.

Example :

PHP:

```
// uniformize line breaks
$introduction = str_replace("\n", "\r", $introduction);
$introduction = str_replace("\r\r", "\r", $introduction);

// explode in several parts
$introduction = explode("\r", $introduction);

// merge on a block
$TBS->MergeBlock('intro', $introduction);
```

DOCX:

```
[intro.val;block=tbs:p]
```